# DynamoDb write batch, [WARN] (invoke@invoke.c:331 errno: No such file or directory) run_dotnet(dotnet_path, &args) failed

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, limit

I try to write batch to aws DynamoDb.
Batch contains 15-20k elements and data is based on 30-40MB txt file.
When I send small batches with <14k elements, DynamoDb saves data and everything is OK.
When I send 15-20k elements in batch, lambda makes multiple retries.
After that lambda sends error:
**[WARN] (invoke@invoke.c:331 errno: No such file or directory) run_dotnet(dotnet_path, &args) failed**

I use c# sdk and crash appears on ExecuteAsync method.
I tried to use try..catch.. to see something more meaningful, but I don't catch exception.
I wonder what message: 'No such file or directory' means.
Google doesn't give me answer to this kind of message exception.
I wonder that It may be some limits on DynamoDb but it's difficult for me to see what limitation I try to exceed.
Crashing-Files are not small and it could be the reason.

Please help.

Comment: Please provide a [minimum reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Note also the `batch-file` tag is for windows batch scripts that are interpreted by `cmd.exe` - Consider replacing the tag with `batch-processing`

Comment: Thank you for help, there was problem with Lambda Memory Size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried many things and at the end I found that there was problem with Memory Size in Lambda. I increased MB and it worked. Lambda message is not so clear when it happens.

Answer (score 0):

There is always a limit on amount of data that can be written in a single batch request.

Check this documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchWriteItem.html

Comment: Making smaller chunks would solve it however effort to increase Lambda Memory Size is much smaller than chunking logic. Thank you for reply.